# Import IntelliJ module into Eclipse project through SVN

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, intellij-idea

I am working with Eclipse, while another developer in our company has developed a large project using IntelliJ. He has used the export to eclipse feature in IntelliJ, and I checked it in through SVN.

But this doesn't seem to do the job. The entire directory structure is still IntelliJ's, and the Eclipse project doesn't recognize the JRE (which I added to the build path) or the jars I added, and not even the packages themselves -- which, as I mentioned, are located within IntelliJa's structure (src > main > java > com.package_name).

Looking everywhere it seems that everyone is going in the other direction: from Eclipse to IntelliJ.

So my question is, is it at all possible to import successfully an IntelliJ project to Eclipse, while maintaining the directory structure so that SVN will still work?

Comment: It seems from the directory structure that this is a Maven project. Do you see a file named `pom.xml` at the root of your project?

Comment: Yes, it was a Maven project, but the developer has created a similar structure in IntelliJ. So it's no longer a Maven project. (And there is a pom.xml, but it's not in use.) Does that make sense?

Comment: Thnigs would have been easier if the developer kept modifying pom.xml and synchronizing his IntelliJ project automatically... You could try to run a `mvn eclipse:eclipse` in your project, perhaps it can generate a working project if your pom.xml is no too much outdated.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "similar structure in IntelliJ". Is there a `src/main/java` directory? Can you run `mvn install` and get it to compile and build?

Comment: Thanks, Nebelmann and Vivin, but I don't want to use Maven. I assume the solution you're offering is not just a one time thing, but something I'll have to do whenever I want to change something in my code? (Instead of the "build automatically" that Eclipse is doing for me.)

Comment: Did you found the solution of you question .?
I am stuck in the same thing.